# SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal (nothing seems to work)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-error

I've been scouring SO for like an hour now and tried every possible fix. Indented and reindented and moved that string around, counted the brackets. Nothing works.
I was just trying to replicate the code posted [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3715) as a solution (so it must've worked for someone at some point).

I keep getting the `SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal` error.

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox
from bokeh.models.widgets import CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(3*np.pi*t)
c = np.cos(3*np.pi*t)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(t=t, s=s, c=c))

plot = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
a = plot.line('t', 's', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6, line_color='blue')
b = plot.line('t', 'c', source=source, line_width=3, line_alpha=0.6, line_color='red')

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Cosinus", "Sinus"], active=[0,1])

checkbox.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(line0=a, line1=b), code="""
    //console.log(cb_obj.active);
    line0.visible = false;
    line1.visible = false;
    for (i in cb_obj.active) {
        //console.log(cb_obj.active[i]);
        if (cb_obj.active[i] == 0) {
            line0.visible = true;
        } else if (cb_obj.active[i] == 1) {
            line1.visible = true;
        }
    }
""")

layout = row(plot, widgetbox(checkbox))

show(layout)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a developer on the VSCode extension. We had an issue with triple quoted strings.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/5012

The fix for this is currently in, but it's only in our development build. To get the fix you can either wait until next week when we do our monthly extension release. Or if you want you could pick up our development build which has our up to the moment fixes.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-build

If you install the development build it will automatically get updated to the full tested release build when that build is released.

Sorry about the annoyance this caused you.

Comment: OMG, thank you! I thought I was going crazy ... the link to script is broken tho https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/master/pvsc-dev-ext.py
But if it'll really be fixed next week, I can wait.

Comment: Yeah, next week should have it. To download the extension just use the direct vsix link if you want. Thanks for reporting that the git script is broken. I'll look at getting that removed or fixed. 

https://pvsc.blob.core.windows.net/extension-builds/ms-python-insiders.vsix

I would just manually install that instead of trying to use the script.